# Como afecta mover esta linea de código? C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity, jerarquía

He pasado dos días intentando resolver un problema, hace poco encontré la solución pero no entiendo porque al mover una linea de código deja de funcionar completamente, soy nuevo en Unity y me gustaria recibir ayuda para entender un poco mas.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController characterController;
    [Header("Opciones de personaje")]
    public float walkSpeed = 6.0f;
    public float runSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;

    private Vector3 move = Vector3.zero;
    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));   //Esta linea de codigo es 
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                move = transform.TransformDirection(move) * runSpeed;
            else
                move = transform.TransformDirection(move) * walkSpeed;

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
 
                move.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
        move.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        characterController.Move(move * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Si reemplazo su posición por antes del if, el salto se vuelve mucho mas pequeño y si aumento la jumpSpeed el objeto no se traslada, simplemente "salta" hasta la posición indicada

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController characterController;
    [Header("Opciones de personaje")]
    public float walkSpeed = 6.0f;
    public float runSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;

    private Vector3 move = Vector3.zero;
    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));   //La reemplazo aqui
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                move = transform.TransformDirection(move) * runSpeed;
            else
                move = transform.TransformDirection(move) * walkSpeed;

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
 
                move.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
        move.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        characterController.Move(move * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

He pensado que quizá es un tema de jerarquía en c# pero no encuentro nada útil, les agradecería ayuda, ya sea una explicación o una fuente que me ayude a entender :3 Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia es que en un código tienes la sentencia dentro de una condición (characterController.isGrounded) donde, si es verdadera se ejecutará esa línea de código y el resto y, si es falsa no se ejecutará esa línea de código.

En el otro código, tienes el mismo código solo que esa línea de código fuera de la condición, por lo que cada vez que se llame a la función Update se ejecutará (es decir, en cada fotograma) independientemente de que se cumpla o no la condición.

Answer (score 0):

Hola en c# no hay gerarquia el alcance de un if es de la linea siguiente con codigo, cuando no tiene llaves y todo lo que esta entre llaves cuando si tiene llaves.

Las diferencias entre tu codigo es que el segundo permite el movimiento cuando esta en el aire, eso da una sensacion de mayor movimiento.

Pero tiene un error

```
move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), /*Reinicia a 0 en cada ciclo --->*/ 0.0f /*Puedes cambiarlo por move.y*/,Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));   //La reemplazo aqui
```

Otra opcion es agregar una variable de impluso en Y.

si quieres un salto mas fluido yo te recomiendo agragar un rigidbody a tu personaje y usar addForce de tipo impulse para aprovechas el motor de fisica.